# a:hover (with an id)background image transition not working in firefox and ie

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

i have some logos which transition on hover but i've always tested with chrome(yeah i messed up)So I just tested it in ff & ie and it's not working (i have the latest versions)

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r6qZw/

and here is the html

```
<a id="facebook" href="http://facebook.com"></a>
```

and the css

```
#facebook {
float: left;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2lAKpSi.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-khtml-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#facebook:hover {
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/L7Jmol5.jpg);
}
```

I know the solution to this is simple but i just couldn't do it. When i remove the background image and just use a color instead, it works but using background image just stops the animation. I still get the second image but it doesn't transition with an animation. I've also tried giving a parent element (like the famous "ul li a" and such)

Can someone help a noob out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-image` is not a transitionable property (except for gradients, and that's not supported in Chrome - IE supports it though!)

The fact that Chrome can transition the image for you is simply an extension of the standard. This is evidenced by how horrible it looks if you rapidly move your mouse over and off of it repeatedly - normal transitions are smooth in spite of this, but the image "transition" is horrible.

Comment: Yet another "what the hell, Chrome?" How *does* it transition the images? Crossfade?

Comment: @BoltClock Looks like a crossfade to me, yup. I tried changing one of the images to something completely different, and it also transitions the size, which is quite neat. But yeah.

Comment: He can use `img` tag with opacity to achieve that effect though, would like you to add that in your answer...

Comment: Sorry for the incredibly late comment and thanks for the lightning fast answer. Yeah it turns out background-image is not completely transitionable (yet) It only works with webkits built after 2012. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg6


@Mr.Alien  i've googled around and used img tag but i hope ff and ie begin using the latest webkits. The code just looks way more cleaner.

Comment: Haha, three hours is nothing - I've had people come back to me months after I answered them!